# Retaining font style while using Text-To-Columns

Tags: vba, excel

When using Text-To-Columns, is there a way to keep the font style of the text within the cell you are using the command on? For example, I have a cell with text in the form: *12345*, **12345**, ***12345***, 12345.

Using Text-To-Columns, I want the end result to be 4 columns with the text retaining its current font style, however the function reverts the text to the style of the 4th '12345'. I tried using Destination:= [code].Font.ColorIndex, but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

```
                        ActiveSheet.Range("M" & k).Select
                        Selection.Font.ColorIndex = ActiveSheet.Range(MyValueAIMS & k).Font.ColorIndex

                        If InStr(ActiveSheet.Range(MyValueAIMS & k).Value, ",") > 0 Then
                            Range(MyValueAIMS & k).Select
                            ActiveSheet.Range(MyValueAIMS & k).Replace _
                                What:=Chr(10), Replacement:="" 'maybe change this so it puts in an actual delimiter?
                                    '.Font.ColorIndex = ActiveSheet.Range(MyValueAIMS & k).Font.ColorIndex
                            Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("M" & k), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
                                Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar _
                                :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), _
                                Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write code to scan through each character in the source cell and move the character along with it's formatting to the destination cell changing the destination cell when a "break" character is reached.

There will be no benefit in using text-to-columns.  There is no easier way of doing this that I know of.

Needless to say it's quite a bit of work.

[This](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/368575-copy-partial-cell-character-format-s-from-one-cell-to-another-an-example.html) page might give you an insight into the sort of code you might write and the properties and methods you might use.

Note that the code is simpler if your formatting in teh source cell is simple as you have suggested).  If the source cell is ALWAYS "nonbold bold nonbold bold" with a delimiting character between you could code differently.

Harvey

Comment: Okay, I'll investigate this and give it a try. Unfortunately, the formatting of the source cell isn't consistent, so I'll no idea where the bold characters are. Thanks!